# Change Namespace URI in Spring SOAP WS

Tags: soap, spring-ws

We have some legacy systems that consume the same `@Endpoint` however each with a different namespace. The payload, implementation and functionality are the same except for the namespace of the `SOAPBody`'s first child element.

How would I replace the namespace of the incoming SOAP request to a generic one before it reaches the `Endpoint`? Tried playing with the `EndpointInterceptor` however unable to find a method to replace the namespace.

**Legacy System 1:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <GetRecordsRequest xmlns="http://www.test.com/system1">
         <maxRecords>100</maxRecords>
      <GetRecordsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Legacy System 2:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <GetRecordsRequest xmlns="http://www.abctest.com/system2">
         <maxRecords>100</maxRecords>
      <GetRecordsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Dear @Rayyan, Could you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?